How to access parent record in JS and HTML LWC
I have below code to show contact related list. How I can pull Account name in HTML and JS file.
HTML
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-card title="Contact">
        Contact List:
        <template for:each={dispVal} for:item="rec">
          <div key={rec.fields.Id.value}>
            {rec.fields.Id.value}
            {rec.fields.Name.value}            
          </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</lightning-card>
</template>

JS
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
export default class NewContactRelatedList extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
dispVal;

@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Contacts',
        fields: ['Contact.Name','Contact.Id','Contact.Account.Name']
    }) myRelatedListRecords({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.dispVal = data.records;
            this.error = undefined;
            console.log('dispVal' + JSON.stringify(this.dispVal));        
        }
        if (error) {
            this.dispVal = undefined;
            this.error = error;
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}


update your HTML code like this
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-card title="Contact">
            Contact List:
            <template for:each={dispVal} for:item="rec">
                <div key={rec.fields.Id.value}>
                    <strong>Contact ID:</strong> {rec.fields.Id.value} <br/>
                    <strong>Contact Name:</strong> {rec.fields.Name.value} <br/>
                    <strong>Account Name:</strong> 
                    <template if:true={rec.fields.Account.value}>
                        {rec.fields.Account.value.fields.Name.value}
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-card>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


added <template if:true={rec.fields.Account.value}> to ensure that the Account field exists before trying to access Account.Name. This prevents any errors if there is a Contact without an associated Account.
*rec.fields.Account.value.fields.Name.value accesses the Name field of the Account related to the Contact.

